# Changing the SkyDrive default path in Windows 8.1

Tags: onedrive, windows-8.1

The deeper integration with SkyDrive is truly beneficial, but my laptop has a somewhat small primary drive (an 128 Gb MSATA SSD), and when possible, i try to move installations and other folders(like Documents and Downloads) to the secondary, 1 Tb drive.

But i couldn't find any option to change the SkyDrive folder (it used to be in the secondary drive prior to the upgrade).

Anyone have some idea how to change it?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit 1:** I've looked for an option to change this folder, to no avail. Really, it could only be a problem if i choose the option to keep my files offline, but it is exactly the option that i was looking for.

**Edit 2:** Trying to install the old desktop app, the installer just quits silently.

**Edit 3:** This question was asked during the Windows 8.1 Preview, when there wasn't such option. Now Microsoft treated the Skydrive folder like the Documents folder, solving the problem completely. I've reassigned the correct answer.

Comment: Have you tried changing the directory from within Skydrive?  You should understand that moving the location of profile directories is actually not supported by Microsoft ( although the process is still documented they warn you have possible problems ) so it might not be possible.

Comment: AFAIK, there is not such option (hence the question). I am aware of the problems of moving the location of the profile folders, and that's exactly why I want to change the configuration of SkyDrive, since the previous version (installable on desktop) had this option.

Comment: I figured that but you didn't mention there wasn't an option.  I don't assume anything when doing troubleshooting questions. Have you tried to install the current Skydrive desktop application.  Can you tell if the Skydrive folder is part of the profile directory?  I have not had a chance to upgrade my Windows 8 Virtual Machine otherwise I would try myself.

Comment: Sorry about my tone. I didn't mean to offend you. I'll edit the post to clarify it.

Comment: Its not possible to offend me.  Anything I say is an attempt to get clarification in order to provide you a solution.

Comment: @Ramhound Your assumption is correct. It creates a SkyDrive folder in the user directory. If you were using a custom before, that folder remains there, but it's pretty much orphaned. I don't even think there is a SkyDrive app anymore.

Comment: Please review the accepted answer in order to pick the one that is relevant now (which means: you CAN change the SkyDrive location in Windows 8.1). Thanks!

Comment: @Timotei The question itself is not relevant anymore, as it was asked during the Preview phase of windows 8.1. Maybe the question titile or tags lacked that information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Windows 8.1 RTM this is possible

In the default This PC view, right-click on SkyDrive in the navigation pane and select **Properties**.

Navigate to the Location tab.  To change the location where SkyDrive syncs its files, simply click the Move button and choose a new location.

[Source](http://winsupersite.com/windows-8/windows-81-tip-move-location-skydrive-folder)

Comment: This is now the correct answer.

Comment: Though whether it is reliable is another matter. Atempting to move my OneDrive folder onto D:  resulting in locking the folder for WEEKS. I had no idea if it was doing anything, so in the end, I disabled SkyDrive completely.

Comment: I promise you it's reliable.

Answer (score 7):

How to change the Windows 8.1 Preview SkyDrive sync directory

1. Kill the SkyDrive Metro app, "SkyDrive.exe" and "FileManager.exe" task in the "Task Manager > Details"
2. Now delete all the files from the directory: C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\SkyDrive\settings
3. Open Regedit and change the following directory value*:
   `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SkyDrive]`

   > "UserFolder"="x:\YourSkyDriveDirectory"
   >   *(If you can't find this directory value search for: `YOURWINDOWSUSERNAME\SkyDrive`)
4. Restart your PC and it should start syncing from/to your new directory.
5. Open the SkyDrive Metro app to confirm your files and new directory.
6. You can now delete the old SkyDrive in C:/Users/%username/ to save some space.

Make sure to enable: (CharmMenu>Settings>Options) "Access all files offline" to upload your offline files.

I also tried the Mklink method but that didn't seem to work for me so I had to dig a little deeper :)

Comment: symlink and folder junctions didn't work? wow, ms ppl surprised me in amount of work they've put into this

Comment: yah, symlinks/junctions worked fine in w7 and w8. Stopped working in w8.1.

Answer (score 3):

In the current Windows 8.1 preview it is not possible to change the Skydrive location, this is confirmed by Microsoft in the following thread:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1_pr-files/how-to-change-location-of-skydrive-folder-in/654d6e2a-fb22-4dae-bc95-d438de54f567?page=1

> Moving the SkyDrive root folder to another location is not currently supported but it is something we'd like to add and think is important to have.

There are however a couple of things to note here:

- The old Skydrive desktop app is no longer supported in 8.1. It's replaced by a built in Skydrive sync including the Windows Store App for Skydrive
- The new Skydrive sync puts all your files into C:\Users\\Skydrive as "stubs". The files are accessible but only takes a few kbs per file.

  - This is the recommended approach for computers with smaller OS drives.
- You can selectively sync which foldes to make available offline and you can also sync the entire library, this can be set from the Windows Store App.

There are also suggestions on how to move the default skydrive location by changing registry settings and it seems to work for some people but not for others, and it's not a supported method.

I'm also looking for a way to do this but I'm waiting for a more stable method than hacking my registry.

HTH

Comment: fyi, have a look at this answer [Changing the SkyDrive default path in Windows 8.1](http://superuser.com/a/643792)

Answer (score 3):

For Windows 8.1

I tried ArnoldV's method and it worked excellent.
If it seems too intense, here's an easier way:

Open an elevated command prompt. This is a really easy way to do it:
Hold the windows key and x. Then press A. If PowerShell opens, then type CMD followed by an enter.

Now copy this code, and the only thing to replace would be **A:\Skydrive** with wherever your new path is. Keep the quotes around your custom path.

Now switch to the elevated command prompt window. Right click the window and then paste the following:

```
taskkill /f /im Skydrive*
taskkill /f /im FileManager*
cd %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\SkyDrive\settings
del * /F /Q
reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Skydrive /v UserFolder /d "A:\Skydrive" /f
shutdown /r /t
```

Press enter to restart afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the Skydrive location much like you do the pre-defined "Documents" - "Music" and "Pictures" etc folders.

Locate your Skydrive folder in:

> C:\Users\USERNAME

Right click on "Skydrive" folder and go to properties.

Under "Location" tab, change the location to your liking.

Apply the change, and move the folder if desired.